# Counter Strike Global Offensive Server Update Script Help

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

does anybody know what the CSGO Server Update Script is? I am trying to make a server on Ubuntu 15.04 and I cannot seem to find the update script... Is it alot like TF2's Server update script? If someone could answer that question that would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only major difference between update scripts on TF2 and CS:GO is the appid you use for SteamCMD.

CS:GO's server appid is `740`.  TF2's server appid is `232250`.